# Writing appSetting to separate *.config file

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a self-hosted web api project, which appSettings are stored in separate location. I've achieved this by using `file=""`

```
<appSettings file="D:\myLocation\api.config">
  </appSettings>
```

Then I'm able to read my settings using this code:

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
```

But when I try to re-write the value, using this code:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["MyKey"].Value = "someNewValue"
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

I'm getting original `app.config` file updated, instead of updating my separate stored file. 
Is there any way of updating external `appSettings` file programmatically? Or maybe there are other best practices of storing settings separately?

Please, ask, if you need more information!

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

Just to prevent comments and answers like "wouldn't it be easier..." - this service is going to work on specific system with Enhanced Write Filter applied. This means, I won't be able to make any persistent changes on the partition. That's why I'm looking for a way to store settings in separate file located on separate partition without EWF. This scenario puts strict limits on how I can resolve the issue. Thank you for understanding!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just read/write directly to your own configuration file?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I've got some specific requirements, which force me to use separate *.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not open the external config file as a regular Xml file and write your changes? This way you dont have to worry about anything else.

Comment: Yes, this is a plan B. I just thought, there is built-in, good-practice way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the name of the config section like this:

```
config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource = "api.config";
```

Comment: Does this code takes relative path to api.config? I really need to be able to specify full physical path to the file.

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit me. ConfigSource takes relative path, but I need to be able to specify full path to the separate config file. It might be on another system disk or even on flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use below.

```
var configFile = new FileInfo("D:\WebsiteABC\Web.config");
var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm,  "/");
configuration.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ConfigSource = "AppSettings.config";
```